# Coinbase API parsing into Swift App returns incorrect formatting

Tags: swift, coinmarketcap

I am using coinmarketcap api to fetch coin prices using the code down below. The data model Coin is also given below after the code as well as the JSON response. I get an error "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format." What should the correct formating look like?

'''

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Alamofire

class CryptoViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    func fetchData() {
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "Accepts": "application/json",
              "X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY": "5dd693fc-6446-44c4-8aaa-75b1bfa4376f"
        ]
        
        AF.request("https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest", headers: headers).response { response in
            guard let data = response.data else { return }
            
            do {
                let coins = try JSONDecoder().decode([Coin].self, from: data)
                print(coins)
            }
            catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

'''

'''

```
import SwiftUI

struct Coin: Decodable {
    
    var slug: String?
    var symbol: String?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case slug = "slug"
        case symbol = "symbol"
    }
}
```

'''

'''

```
success({
    data =     (
                {
            "circulating_supply" = 18697137;
            "cmc_rank" = 1;
            "date_added" = "2013-04-28T00:00:00.000Z";
            id = 1;
            "last_updated" = "2021-05-02T14:22:02.000Z";
            "max_supply" = 21000000;
            name = Bitcoin;
            "num_market_pairs" = 9549;
            platform = "<null>";
            quote =             {
                USD =                 {
                    "last_updated" = "2021-05-02T14:22:02.000Z";
                    "market_cap" = "1063000586851.752";
                    "percent_change_1h" = "0.09591311";
                    "percent_change_24h" = "-1.05109813";
                    "percent_change_30d" = "-4.45794679";
                    "percent_change_60d" = "11.80459387";
                    "percent_change_7d" = "14.06195861";
                    "percent_change_90d" = "69.54985569999999";
                    price = "56853.65555441735";
                    "volume_24h" = "40969975368.50657";
                };
            };
            slug = bitcoin;
            symbol = BTC;
            tags =             (
                mineable,
                pow,
                "sha-256",
                "store-of-value",
                "state-channels",
                "coinbase-ventures-portfolio",
                "three-arrows-capital-portfolio",
                "polychain-capital-portfolio",
                "binance-labs-portfolio",
                "arrington-xrp-capital",
                "blockchain-capital-portfolio",
                "boostvc-portfolio",
                "cms-holdings-portfolio",
                "dcg-portfolio",
                "dragonfly-capital-portfolio",
                "electric-capital-portfolio",
                "fabric-ventures-portfolio",
                "framework-ventures",
                "galaxy-digital-portfolio",
                "huobi-capital",
                "alameda-research-portfolio",
                "a16z-portfolio",
                "1confirmation-portfolio",
                "winklevoss-capital",
                "usv-portfolio",
                "placeholder-ventures-portfolio",
                "pantera-capital-portfolio",
                "multicoin-capital-portfolio",
                "paradigm-xzy-screener"
            );
            "total_supply" = 18697137;
        }, ...
```

'''

Comment: Now I get an errror that says "The data couldn’t be read because it is missing."

Comment: Replace `print(error.localizedDescription)` with `print(error)`. It tells you exactly what's wrong and where

Comment: '2021-05-02 21:12:54.781115+0300 CryptoPrices[23030:1106641] [] nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed
typeMismatch(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "quote", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "USD", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "price", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode String but found a number instead.", underlyingError: nil))' Now I get this error.

Comment: 'struct Data: Decodable {
    var data: [Coin]
}

struct Coin: Decodable {
    var slug: String?
    var symbol: String?
    var quote: Quote?
}

struct Quote: Decodable {
    var USD: USD?
}

struct USD: Decodable {
    var last_updated: String
    var price: String?
}'

Comment: The error says that `price` is `Double`. The (NS)Dictionary output in the question is ambiguous, because strings and numbers cannot be distinguished definitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think you might want to remove the API key in your example and reset it.

Regarding your question. Your response starts with a `data` property. To parse this you would need start your struct there as well.

So something like this should work;

```
struct Coins: Decodable {
    let data: [Coin]

    struct Coin: Decodable {
        let symbol: String
        let slug: String
        let quote: [String: Quote]
    }

    struct Quote: Decodable {
        let price: Double
    }
}
```

I'm nesting the structs to preserve the namespace. Everything is pretty related. If you ever need access to one of them on it's own you could pull them out.

Also you can omit the CodingKeys, since the key is the same as your variable name. Also I don't think you need optionals there, but I'm not completely familiar with the API.

Furthermore I think you get only 1 set of data back and not an array of coins. So I would do the following here;

```
let coins = try JSONDecoder().decode(Coins.self, from: data)
```

Comment: Now I get an errror that says "The data couldn’t be read because it is missing."

Comment: Ok I actually figured it out. Now I need to access to the price.

Comment: See my updated answer for accessing the pricing!

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I am trying to populate the @Published coins array. So I created a separate model called CoinData.

Comment: 'struct Data: Decodable {
    var data: [CoinData]
}

struct CoinData: Decodable {
    var slug: String?
    var symbol: String?
    //var quote: Quote?
}

struct Quote: Decodable {
    var USD: USD?
}

struct USD: Decodable {
    var last_updated: String
    var price: Double?
}

struct Coin: Decodable {
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var slug: String?
    var symbol: String?
}'

Now, what is a good way of populating the array given the code below.

Comment: 'do {
                let coinsData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Data.self, from: data)
                
                
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    for c in coinsData {
                        self.coins.append(Coin(slug: c.slug, symbol: c.symbol))
                    }
                }
 
                
            }'

Comment: Well you already get a Coin array back so why not use that straight away? Your data key is already of type `[Coin]`. So simply using `coinsData.data` will return the type `[Coin]`. Then just do `self.coins = coinsData.data`.

Just make sure that `self.coins` is of type `[Coin]`. There is no need for all the appending and looping that way.

Comment: @cemgem if these answers resolved your issue, you can mark it as solved by clicking the checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

You are parsing an entire response as an array of coins, but the actual data, that you are interested in, is located under `data` key, therefore you need to add an additional layer

```swift
struct Coins: Decodable {
    let coins: [Coin]
}
```

and decode it instead of `Coin`

```swift
let coins = try JSONDecoder().decode(Coins.self, from: data)
```